# How can I attach data from a hash to an ActiveRecord collection?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, data-structures, rails-activerecord

I have data from an external service (Google Analytics API) that I fetched into a hash (could be a struct, array, not important). It basically contains analytics information for certain records of a model.

I want to display that data joined together with the details for the record from my database in a table, and I want to know if there is a way to "attach" the data to the ActiveRecord objects so they have another method I can call, for example `nr_clicks` that can be populated from my external data object.

So I would access it something like this:

```
<tr>
  <td><%= item.name %></td>
  <td><%= item.price %></td>
  <td><%= item.nr_clicks %></td>
</tr>
```

Or is the safe and easy way to just ask for the data in another object?

```
<tr>
  <td><%= item.name %></td>
  <td><%= item.price %></td>
  <td><%= @item_clicks[item.id] %></td>
</tr>
```

**Note**: I don't intend to store the data in the database for now, so it should work with data on the fly.

Comment: You could use `serialize` [docs](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/AttributeMethods/Serialization/ClassMethods/serialize) to store the hash/array in a text column in the database if that's what you're looking for.

Comment: No, that's not what I'm looking for, I want to be able to use the data I got without commiting it to the database. Kind of a temporary field, that never makes it into the db, but to the view it seems like it's coming from the same source as other attributes on the item.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so just a method with an instance variable then?

```
class Item

  def nr_clicks
    @clicks ||= get_clicks
  end

  private

  def get_clicks
    #code to get data from analytics
  end
end
```

Comment: Kind of like that, except that I have a collection of the data already in memory, so no need to do it on an individual basis. The class shouldn't know about the api or as the matter a fact about the data being added to it.

Comment: Then just add attr_accessors and set them after you initialize the item?

Comment: Hmm.. is there a way I can dynamically add accessors after I initialize the items? I don't want to pollute the model with the extra code. I'm already using decorators, that could be a place to put that in, but how do I define accessors in a decorator? (Draper gem)

Comment: Don't use Draper really to be honest I'm afraid.

Comment: Why are you afraid? I'm already using it for adding view-related methods to my models, and it works well, as long as I'm not overriding original methods :)

Comment: In that context afraid just means I can't help you on that.